# object constructed but still null

Tags: java, debugging

What is wrong with this source code?

```
 1  package Core;
 2  
 3  import java.sql.*;
 4  
 5  public class Course extends Model {
 6      
 7      protected int id;
 8      protected String title;
 9      
10      public Course(int id) {
11          this.id = id;
12      }
13      
14       public static Course getNew(ResultSet res) {
15          try {
16              Course c;
17              c = new Course(res.getInt("course_id"));
18              return c;
19          } catch(SQLException e) {
20              return null;
21          }
22      }
23      
24      @Override
25      public String toString() {
26          return this.title;
27      }
28  }
```

I've set breakpoints on lines 17, 18 and 11 (mentioned in the order of the execution flow), the object is certainly constructed, yet on line 18 it will return a `null` instead of the object.

What am I missing?

Please don't tell me how bad static methods are, I know that. Help me understand why is this happenning and how to fix it.

I'm using netbeans + glassfish + java 7 (openjdk) on linux x64.

**Addendum**

Ok so the problem may be in the way I'm calling it - I'm using reflection and generics.

The caller looks like this

```
 1  package Core;
 2  
 3  import java.sql.*;
 4  import java.util.*;
 5  import java.lang.reflect.*;
 6  
 7  /**
 8   * Represents storable elements in a database
 9   */
10  public abstract class Model {
11      /**
12       * this attribute is common to all models of the app
13       * this way we can reuse the same connection for
14       * everything (good or bad, depending on the project's requirements; in
15       * our case it's good - this should be a simple application, no mysql
16       * replication and things like that)
17       */
18      protected static Connection conn = null;
19      
20       public static void setConnection(Connection c) {
21          Model.conn = c;
22      }
23       
24       public static void initStatements() throws SQLException {
25           
26       }
27       
28       protected <T extends Model> HashMap<String, Model> resultsetMap(Class<T> cls, ResultSet res) {
29           HashMap<String, Model> data = new HashMap<String, Model>();
30           Method m;
31           try {
32              m = cls.getMethod("getNew", ResultSet.class);
33              
34           } catch(Exception e) {
35               return null;
36           }
37           
38           
39           try {
40               while(res.next()) {
41                   T obj = (T) m.invoke(null, res);
42                   data.put(obj.toString(), obj);
43               }
44           }
45           catch(Exception e) {
46               return null;
47           }
48           return data;
49       }
50       
51       @Override
52       public abstract String toString();
53       
54       public static Model getNew(ResultSet res) {
55           return null;
56       }
57  }
```

On line 41 I'm calling the above method `getNew()`. I end up with `null`s in the map, both for the keys and the values.

The method on line 28 is called like this

```
return this.<Course>resultsetMap(Course.class, res);
```

Sorry for all the mess, **I've found the** (stupid, as usual) **cause**: the `title` of the `Course` class is left unset.

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting an exception? Add a printStackTrace or similar before you return null in the catch clause.

Comment: You sure you aren't running into that `SQLException` you appear to be swallowing? You return null from the catch block, perhaps debug that.

Comment: Maybe you should specify what are you debugging with, and where exactly do you see the null value. When run

Comment: Does 'c' have any scope outside of the function / class? If its being constructed and then disappearing Id look to that first.

Comment: I think line 17, object was not created and res.getInt(...) throwing SQLException which is ending up as return null;

Comment: Add `System.out.println("Course id: " + c.id);` before line 18 and check the console output in runtime. If c is null, invocation of getNew should result in NullPointerException. Otherwise, I suspect that you have SQLException. Also, try to clean rebuild the project to make sure you're debugging the actual code).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you reach line 18, then it can't be null. But if you are debugging an older version, or you just don't reach line 18, it can be that you enter the `catch` block with an exception.

So, rule of thumb - don't discard exceptions. For a start, use `ex.printStackTrace()` to see it in the console.

Then try directly `return new Course(res.getInt("course_id"));`

Comment: There is no exception, the return on line 18 is really hit. Just before returning I mouse over the variable `c` and I see a `null`. I've `clean & build`, then `deploy`, then `debug`, so it should be the current version, shouldn't it?

Comment: well that's completely useless since there is NO exception whatsoever. Read carefully what I'm saying, I'm no newbie in programming.

Comment: @Flavius If you are debugging in Eclipse, you can't be sure from where the return was done. Eclipse debugger shows it with errors.

Comment: There's really no exception, even with `return new ...` and a breakpoint on the line with the newly inserted `e.printStackTrace()` in the catch block right before the `return null` statement.

Think about it for a second: if there would be an SQLException, the object wouldn't even be constructed at all. But the execution flow does go into the constructor.

I'm using netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

If on breakpoint at 18 c is not null and the function returns null, you have SQLException happened.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for all the mess, I've found the (stupid, as usual) cause: the `title` of the `Course` class is left unset.